# CAPL CANalyzer getting frames every 10ms

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, canalyzer

I am new to CAPL and CANalyzer,I am trying to read from CAN and I want every frame to be read every 10ms but I can't find any solution.

I tried with a timer but as I understood, every event has to finish before starting another so the timer doesn't help considering that the frames are read from one function.

I also tried to divide it in different functions but I couldn't get them to send the data from one to another.

```
variables {...}

on message CAN1.*
{
 setTimer(myTimer,2000);
 //for() reading from CAN1

}

on timer myTimer
{
 tile.FDF=1;
 tile.dataLength=64;
 tile.can=2; 

 while(tileData<endOfData)
 {
  //for() reading every byte from the tile
 }
 
 output(tile);
}
```

I need to read every frame row from the tile every 10ms, right now that happens every few nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it is not clear, what you want to process and how, nor what a *tile* is, so I can just give you pseudo code here. Change `CAN1.*` in the message handler to whatever message you are interested in.

What about storing the timestamp when you last processed the data and only process again, when 10 ms have passed?

E.g.

```
variables {
  dword tsLastProcessed;
}

on message CAN1.*
{
  // timeNow is incremented every 10 us
  if((timeNow() - tsLastProcessed) < 1000) { 
    return;
  }
  /* else */

  tsLastProcessed = timeNow();

  <process data>
}
```

Comment: The issue with that idea is that the processed time is too fast, in nanoseconds and it doesn't even register it, even with timeNowNS() it just displays the same number so I can't use this idea because the interval doesn't change. 
I couldn't find anything to display the correct time the data is displayed because it is very fast and capl only displays first 3 nanoseconds

Comment: @notBianca `timeNowNS` will get the current simulation time. That is the _correct_ time. If several messages appear within a few nano seconds, that method will be triggered several times with the same timestamp of course. Nevertheless, that will still work. Apart from that, I doubt that you really have to handle all messages on CAN1 for your sue case, but these are details only you know.